# How to convert date into DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can someone help me with SQL Date format?

The following statement

```
 SELECT convert(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),113) 
returns 
  04 Aug 2011 08:08:08.
```

I want the results like

```
Aug-04-2011 08:08:08
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think its:

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),120)
```

EDIT:

This will work:

```
SELECT datename(day, GETDATE()) + '-' 
   + substring(datename(month, GETDATE()),0,4) + '-' 
   + datename(year, GETDATE()) + ' '
   + datename(hh, GETDATE()) + ':'
   + datename(mi, GETDATE()) + ':'
   + datename(ss, GETDATE())
```

SECOND EDIT:

```
SELECT substring(datename(month, GETDATE()),0,4) + '-' 
   + datename(day, GETDATE()) + '-' 
   + datename(year, GETDATE()) + ' '
   + datename(hh, GETDATE()) + ':'
   + datename(mi, GETDATE()) + ':'
   + datename(ss, GETDATE())
```

THIRD EDIT:

```
select substring(datename(month, GETDATE()),0,4) + '-'     
    + right(datename(day, GETDATE())+100,2) + '-'     
    + datename(year, GETDATE()) + ' '    
    + right(datename(hh, GETDATE())+100,2) + ':'    
    + right(datename(mi, GETDATE())+100,2) + ':'    
    + right(datename(ss, GETDATE())+100,2)
```

Comment: I have corrected my posting, sorry. I needed the date MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format.

Comment: It was close. It returned Aug-4-2011 8:59:51

Comment: The thrid query returned the date in the correct format.  Is it HH24 format?

Comment: Thank you! Both your solution and Andriy's solution work perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Date), 3) + '-' +
  RIGHT(100 + DAY(Date), 2) + '-' +
  DATENAME(YEAR, Date) + ' ' +
  CONVERT(varchar, Date, 108)
FROM (SELECT Date = GETDATE()) s
```

Comment: Perfect. It returned Aug-04-2011 09:00:49. Is it HH24 format?

Comment: @rk1962: You can be absolutely sure. It's past 4 pm in my part of the world and it returns `Aug-04-2011 16:15:45`. Why, you can simply replace `GETDATE()` with an arbitrary timestamp to make sure.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Both your solution and Steve's solution work perfectly!  Unfortunately, I can pick only one answer.

Comment: @rk1962: Fine with me, I'm glad both for you and for Steve!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in convert won't allow you to format your date exactly as you desire, unfortunately.

With a little manipulation, you can get there though:

```
SELECT stuff(stuff(convert(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),113), 3, 1, '-'), 7, 1, '-')
```

You could put this in a UDF and call that whenever you want your date formatted in this manner.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Actually, I wanted in MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think 109 format is not HH24 format. Besides, it returns an extra space: SELECT stuff(stuff(convert(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),109), 4, 1, '-'), 7, 1, '-') Aug- 4-2011 8:38:32.  I needed Aug-04-2011 08:38:32 (in 24 hours format)

Comment: then you'll have to use something like stevieg's query below where he concats it all together piece by piece. or, handle the date formatting on whatever front-end as it's far more efficient

Comment: calling UDF decreases overall query performance so be careful!